# BEP20 How to exclude the burn wallet from the maxlimit function

Tags: solidity, remix, erc20, bep20

Am trying to create a project and new to solidity.
I added a max limit to prevent whale wallets.
The limit is 150m tokens and i would like to burn a higher amount, how can i exclude the burn adress 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 from this function.

Codes:

@ **function _transfer(**

```
 uint256 contractBalanceRecepient = balanceOf(to);
 require(contractBalanceRecepient + amount <= _maxWalletToken, "Exceeds maximum wallet token amount (150,000,000)");
```

kind regards Kevin!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the condition in `require()` so that it only applies for addresses that are not 0x0.

```
require(
    (
        contractBalanceRecepient + amount <= _maxWalletToken
        && to != address(0x0)
    ),
    "Exceeds maximum wallet token amount (150,000,000)"
);
```

*Note: Most burn implementations do not transfer the tokens to `0x0`. Instead, they just lower the total supply, lower the sender balance and emit the `Transfer()` event as if they were transfering to 0x0 - without performing the actual transfer... But your way (actual transfer to 0x0) is possible as well.*